# after install ElastAlert, not running

Tags: elasticsearch, error-handling, elastic-stack, elastalert

im install elastalert plugin to kibana,
and downloaded clone github ElastAlert,
and config basic file Config.Yaml
but not running 
this error:

```
root@l-elk1:~# python elastalert/elastalert/elastalert.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "elastalert/elastalert/elastalert.py", line 19, in <module>
    import kibana
  File "/home/ituser/elastalert/elastalert/kibana.py", line 5, in <module>
    from util import EAException
  File "/home/ituser/elastalert/elastalert/util.py", line 8, in <module>
    from auth import Auth
  File "/home/ituser/elastalert/elastalert/auth.py", line 4, in <module>
    from aws_requests_auth.aws_auth import AWSRequestsAuth
ImportError: No module named aws_requests_auth.aws_auth
```

Answer (score 1):

This error show a missing requirement dependency. Inside your checkout run the command:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

And then re execute elastalert.